# How to append new data onto a new line

Tags: python, file-io, append

My code looks like this:

```
def storescores():

   hs = open("hst.txt","a")
   hs.write(name)
   hs.close()
```

so if I run it and enter "Ryan"
then run it again and enter "Bob"
the file hst.txt looks like

```
RyanBob
```

instead of

```
Ryan
Bob
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 117):

If you want a newline, you have to write one explicitly. The usual way is like this:

```
hs.write(name + "\n")
```

This uses a backslash escape, `\n`, which Python converts to a newline character in string literals. It just concatenates your string, `name`, and that newline character into a bigger string, which gets written to the file.

It's also possible to use a multi-line string literal instead, which looks like this:

```
"""
"""
```

Or, you may want to use string formatting instead of concatenation:

```
hs.write("{}\n".format(name))
```

All of this is explained in the [Input and Output](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) chapter in the tutorial.

Answer (score 36):

In Python >= 3.6 you can use new [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) feature:

```
with open('hst.txt', 'a') as fd:
    fd.write(f'\n{name}')
```

Please notice using '[with statment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)' will automatically close the file when 'fd' runs out of scope

Answer (score 29):

All answers seem to work fine. If you need to do this *many times*, be aware that writing

```
hs.write(name + "\n")
```

constructs a new string in memory and appends that to the file.

More efficient would be

```
hs.write(name)
hs.write("\n")
```

which does not create a new string, just appends to the file.

Comment: This is a tradeoff between constructing a new string in memory with `BINARY_ADD` vs doing a `LOAD_FAST` to get hs(can be optimized away outsize the loop), `LOAD_ATTR` to get `write`, and a `CALL_FUNCTION`(relatively high overhead) twice, so it may depend on the size of the `name` string. In the end, benchmarking is the best way to see(and only if you need this speed-up).

Answer (score 26):

The answer is not to add a newline after writing your string. That may solve a different problem. What you are asking is how to add a newline ***before*** you start appending your string. If you want to add a newline, but only if one does not already exist, you need to find out first, by reading the file.

For example,

```
with open('hst.txt') as fobj:
    text = fobj.read()

name = 'Bob'

with open('hst.txt', 'a') as fobj:
    if not text.endswith('\n'):
        fobj.write('\n')
    fobj.write(name)
```

You might want to add the newline after name, or you may not, but in any case, it isn't the answer to your question.

Comment: This method is key to appending to JSON documents, where an extra newline at either the top or bottom of the file is punishable by death. You can't blindly add it; it must be conditional on whether something already exists.

Comment: @ExcelHelp if the question mentioned json, I would have recommended using json load/dump with the desired formatting. The filename is `hst.txt`. I would not recommend manual parsing of a json, except perhaps as an exercise.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. And I was able to solve it by using a formatter.

```
file_name = "abc.txt"
new_string = "I am a new string."
opened_file = open(file_name, 'a')
opened_file.write("%r\n" %new_string)
opened_file.close()
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

There is also one fact that you have to consider.
You should first check if your file is empty before adding anything to it. Because if your file is empty then I don't think you would like to add a blank new line in the beginning of the file. This code

1. first checks if the file is empty
2. If the file is empty then it will  simply add your input text to the file else it will add a new line and then it will add your text to the file. *You should use a try catch for `os.path.getsize()` to catch any exceptions.*

**Code**:

```
import os

def storescores():
hs = open("hst.txt","a")
if(os.path.getsize("hst.txt") > 0):
   hs.write("\n"+name)
else:
   hs.write(name)

hs.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

I presume that all you are wanting is simple string concatenation:

```
def storescores():

   hs = open("hst.txt","a")
   hs.write(name + " ")
   hs.close()
```

Alternatively, change the " " to "\n" for a newline.

Comment: He wants a newline between them, not a space. (It's hard to tell from the question because his formatting is broken, but if you look at the question source, he typed a newline.)

Comment: Thanks - I did address that just in case but I hadn't checked the formatting.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I'm new to this website and couldn't quite get my head around the formatting of questions but I've got it now, thanks

Comment: @user3320839: Usually when I edit a question I add a comment explaining what I did, but in this case I was pretty sure you would probably figure it out on your own. And no harm done; nobody writes perfect questions their first try.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('echo "' + YOURTEXT + '" >> hello.txt',shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open("Python_Programs/files_forhndling.txt","a+")
inpt=str(input("Enter anything:\n>>"))
f.write(inpt)
f.write("\n")
print("Data inserted Successfully")
f.close()
```

> welcome to file handling
>
> new line
>
> file handling in python
>
> 123456
>
> 78875454

## ✔ Output  CLICK BELOW & SEE ✔

[image: OUTPUT 1]

[image: CODE]

Answer (score -5):

You need to change parameter "a" => "a+".
Follow this code bellows:

```
def storescores():
hs = open("hst.txt","a+")
```

Comment: Have you tried your own code. I don't think it is working.

Comment: Yes. Ofcouse it's working. I usually use it in my project!

Comment: a and a+ are the same thing

Comment: 'a+' isn't the exact solution, and maybe don't implicitly suggest leaving the resource open by not explicitly including the close in your example. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This "a" option helped me a lot, **r** = Open text file for reading.  Prepend; **r+** = Open for reading and writing.  Prepend; **w** = Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. Write; **w+** = Open for reading and writing.  Write; **a** = Open for writing. Append; **a+** = Open for reading and writing. Append.