# open() in append mode is not behaving as expected

Tags: python-3.x, file, append

i am trying to create a program that asks to the user what they want to do to a file read/append/delete the file.

```
FileName = open(input("Enter file name: "))
ReadFile = FileName.read()
Decision = input("Do you want to read/delete/append to the file?: ")
if Decision == "read":
    print(ReadFile)
    FileName.close()
elif Decision == "append":
    Append = input("Type what you want to add: ")
    with open("FileName","a") as file:
        file.write(Append)
```

but when i check the file the it doesn't append it

Comment: This will show you how to append to a file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839803/how-to-append-new-data-onto-a-new-line.  For all files operations read this: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're not actually opening the same file. You're asking the user for input to specify a file's location for reading that file, but should they choose to "append" the file, you have them append to a file that has nothing to do with the file they specified. You're having the user append a file called `"FileName"`. You have hard coded that string as the file's location when the user chooses to "append".

Here, `FileName` is **not** a string representing the file's location. This is an object representing the file.

```py
FileName = open(input("Enter file name: "))
```

You had the user enter a string to the file's path, but you didn't store that string value. You used that value to `open()` a file up for reading.

Here, you're opening a file called `"FileName"` in what is likely the directory python started in, since there's no path visible here.

```py
    with open("FileName","a") as file:
        file.write(Append)
```

Go look in your starting directory and see if you've created a new file called `"FileName"`.

Keep in mind, if you open a file with `mode="a"`, and that file does not exist, a new file will be created.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

I would also like to use this moment to inform you about [PEP8, Python's styling guide.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) It's not law, but following it will help other Python programmers help you quicker.

With that said, consider making your code snippet look more like the following code:

```py
filename = input("Enter file name: ")
decision = input("Do you want to read/delete/append to the file?: ")
if decision == "read":
    with open(filename) as file:
        print(file.read())

elif decision == "append":
    append = input("Type what you want to add: ")
    with open(filename, "a") as file:
        file.write(append)
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful you explained it very well