# How to use \n escape character in print command after typecasting to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
var1=54
var2=76
print(100*(str(var1+var2)))
```

output comes to be:

```
130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130130......
```

My question is how to write the answer in different lines like:

```
130
130
.
.
```

I tried using this `command:print(100*(str(var1+var2)\n))`
But it's not correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append new data onto a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839803/how-to-append-new-data-onto-a-new-line)

Answer (score 2):

```
var1=54
var2=76
print(100*(str(var1+var2) + '\n'))
```

Prints:

```
130
130
130

...and so on.
```

---

Note: personally, for readability I'd use:

```
for _ in range(100):
    print(var1+var2)
```