# How to use /n in Python3?

Tags: python, newline

In order to get the output line by line and not after each other, I want to start using /n command.

Here is the piece of code where I think it should be placed:

```
password_for = input('This password is for: ')
your_pass =  'Your password for {} is: {}'.format(password_for, password)

save_path = '/Users/"MyUsername"/Desktop'
name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
with open(completeName, "a+") as file1:
    file1.write(your_pass)
```

The /n command should be used to get the text that's supposed to be written (output), line by line like this:

```
Input 1
input 2
```

But now the output is working like this:

```
Input1Input2
```

Maybe /N isn't the solution? Let me know!

Comment: What does the `/n` command mean?

Comment: @tobias i guess he mean new line.

Comment: Yes I want my input to be:
input 1
Input 2

While now it is like this:
input 1Input2

Comment: Use ```\n``` - means New line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append new data onto a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839803/how-to-append-new-data-onto-a-new-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some characters must be "escaped" in order to enter them into a string. In this case, you want a newline character which is written `\n` in Python.

Anyway, to answer your question:

```
with open(completeName, "a+") as file1:
    file1.write(your_pass + '\n')
```

This will concatenate the string in `your_pass` with the string containing one newline character and then call `file1.write`.

Comment: Thanks Tobias!! So by following your step, you kind of reroute the outcome, so in this case a newline character, and which will then call file1.write. Makes sense!

Comment: One small correction. `\n` is the new line code in all programming languages, at least that I can think of,, not just Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
password_for = input('This password is for: ')
your_pass =  'Your password for {} is: {}'.format(password_for, password)

save_path = '/Users/"MyUsername"/Desktop'
name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
with open(completeName, "a+") as file1:
    file1.write(your_pass + '\n')  # You need to place '\n' here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with string concatenation operator i.e.  "**+ operator**" like given below:

`file1.write(your_pass + '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your code:-

```
+ '\n'
```

In the last line:-

```
file1.write(your_pass + '\n')
```