# Appending at new line in Python using csv library

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am unable to handle case where user forgot to put newline.

I am trying to append new line to a csv file in python using below code -

```
with open(local_file_location, 'a') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

But in case if file do not have a new line it simply appends to same last line for the first time. And I am not sure how to handle that.

Ex-
Input-

```
1,2,3,4 <no-newline>
```

add row - {a,b,c,d}
Output-

```
1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d
```

but I want handle output in this event case to be as below -

```
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d
```

Note: it should just append as well in case user file already have a new line.-> which current program does perfectly.

Let me know what can I do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append new data onto a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839803/how-to-append-new-data-onto-a-new-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a file [ends with](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/endswith) a newline.

```py
with open(local_file_location, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

if data.endswith('\n'):
    # some logic
```